Is there a security risk with the root resource in my AWS API Gateway
I have an AWS API Gateway (REST) set up that includes a single resource -- a /{proxy+} route that routes requests to a lambda. The /{proxy+} resource has IAM Authorization enabled. When I look in the AWS Console, I find that the /{proxy+} route is nested under a root / route that has a "Mock Integration", and no authorization is enabled. I find that when I make a request to the / route without an IAM signed token, I get 403.
My question is:

Do requests to the root / route go through the /{proxy+} integration anyway and therefore get filtered by the IAM Authorization requirement of the proxy route?
Is there any security risk because I do not have IAM authorization enabled on the root resource? I couldn't figure out how to enable it in CDK.

